# Scalar vs Vector signal Quantization

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, quantization

I am studying about scalar vs vector quantization, and I have an assignment to implement (in MATLAB) a scalar quantizer , using the Lloyd-Max algorithm, and a vector quantizer via k-means clustering.

The **vector** quantizer works in the R<sup>2</sup> vector space, so its input is a tuple of samples (input vector) and its output is also a two dimensional vector, corresponding to the centroid vector of the quantization region.

I am told that in order for the comparisons between the two quantizers to be accurate, I need to keep the *number of bits per sample*, **constant**. For example, in a **n-bit scalar** quantizer, there are 2<sup>n</sup> quantization regions, in one of which, a sample will get quantized into.

The equivalent **vector** quantizer, will have **2n** bits per input tuple, so that each sample is still represented by **n** bits.
So, with that logic, I think that the **vector** quantizer should have 2<sup>2n</sup> quantization/Voronoi regions.

I have to quantize an equal number of samples from a Gaussian source (source **A**), and from an AR(5) Random process (source **B**). From what I've studied, I think that the **scalar** quantizer is expected to perform a better quantization of source **A** (in the MSE-sense) and the **vector** quantizer should perform better in the AR process (source **B**), where the samples are correlated with each other.

However, when I quantize both of the forementioned sources, and compute the MSE between the original and the quantized signal, the vector quantizer gives a smaller MSE for both sources. So the vector quantizer, is more efficient (in the MSE-sense) for both the sources, which I think is wrong, as it should be more efficient only for the Autoregressive Random process and not for the Gaussian source, as well.

(I calculate the MSE as :`mse(input_signal - quantized_signal)`, so there's nothing wrong there.)

So my questions are:

1. Should (theoretically) the vector quantizer be more efficient in quantizing both the sources or only in the case of the AR process?
2. The **vector** quantizer equivalent of a **n-bit scalar** quantizer, should have **2n** or **2<sup>2n</sup>** quantization/Voronoi regions (second argument/cluster number of kmeans() ).

If needed I will post the MATLAB code, as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I am stuck on this for some days.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: The Lloyd-Max-Algorithm should yield a uniform quantizer (i.e. a linear quantization function) with a Gaussian source. Have you checked if it really does?

Comment: @Max I am asked to design a **non-uniform** scalar quantizer. I do this by selecting random values for the centroids of each region, in a given range . After the random selection of centroids, I run the Lloyd-Max algorithm.

Comment: Could you also provide the MSE that you currently get for both cases?

Comment: I have a N-bit scalar quantizer, where N=[2 3 4] , so i am running the **vector** quantizer for k=[16 64 256] (k is the argument of kmeans, ie. the number of quantization regions/clusters)

Comment: Source **A** : For the **scalar** case: MSE = [0.1126 0.0333 0.0134] , for the **vector** case : MSE = [0.1023 0.0275 0.0061] .

Comment: Source **B** : For the **scalar** case: MSE = [0.1520 0.0445 0.0121] , for the **vector** case : MSE = [0.1295 0.0348 0.0076]

Comment: What I mean is: Lloyd-Max should **converge to a uniform quantizer** given that the training signal is Gaussian. If it does not do so, either the signal isn't Gaussian or something is wrong with the algorithm.

Comment: @Max The algorithm does not converge to a uniform quantizer, but to a non-uniform one, which is what I actually want. Why are you suggesting that it should converge to a uniform one? Is this a property of the algorithm that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, i made a mistake. It would converge to a uniform quantizer if the training signal was **uniform**. Yours is **gaussian**, so of course the quantizer will be non-uniform. My bad.

Comment: You could still check output of the algorithm, though. The centroid density should look something like a Gaussian bell curve.

Comment: For **2-bit scalar** run, I get the following centroids : [-1.5137 -0.4300  0.4709 1.5023] , which I think is gaussian-like

Comment: Hard to tell from just 4 centroids, but it seems to be right.

Comment: I also checked it for a 3-bit and 4-bit scalar run, and evaluated the results by running ksdensity() and plotting the result.  What about the vector quantizer? for N=[2 3 4] , the equivalent k (i.e number of quantization regions/clusters) should be k=[16 64 256] ? Also, should the vector one , be more efficient in both the sources?

Comment: Your numbers are correct. Try some higher bitrates, the scalar one should bei optimal for uncorrelated signals.